# Don't know the best way to check for a console error in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm fairly new-ish to coding and I hear people mention about using Firebug to check for console errors. Doing a quick Google search it seems like Firebug is used with Firefox only (unless I'm mistaken).

I know this is a subjective question but still a question that would help me out greatly.
What would be the best way to check for console errors in Chrome?

Also, can console errors only be checked on a website that is live or can I check on local files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually F12 open the "firebug" in chrome. You have different tabs, one of these is "Console". Console is used mostly to get javascript and jquery errors. You could also check "Network" tab because you can get there some interesting information about any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome comes with [great (the best?) already built-in tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) for debugging during development.

On Mac:
Press `CMD+ALT+J`

On Windows:
Press `CTRL+SHIFT+J`

You can check both live and local sites. See also [Using the Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: Ah, thanks. But when the console comes up, its blank. Does this just mean there's no errors?

Comment: Yes, most likely it does.

Comment: Ah brilliant. And does this work with local files or do they need to be hosted?

Comment: It works with local files. Please see the links in my answer, they provide tons of information

Comment: You have to open the console before loading a new web site. If the web site is loaded, the console and firebug could be empty. There is a checkbox, if you make right-click on the console, it says "Preserver Log upon navigation". If you check that, you'll save the console log although you load another site.